# X is a uniform random variable [0,1]. Find P(X>=2/3) and E(X^2020).

Tags: probability

X is a uniform random variable [0,1]. Find P(X>=2/3) and E(X^2020).

It's 1-2/3 for the first part but I don't get how as well as the second part.

Comment: Are you allowed to use calculus (i.e. integration)? if so, the second question is trivial.

Comment: @zugzug Yes calculus is allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDF is given by $1$ on $[0,1]$. Recall that given a PDF on some set, the probability a random variable lies in some interval $[a,b]$ in that domain is the integral from $a$ to $b$ of the PDF. So for the first, integrate this function from $2/3$ to $1$.

For the second, use the definition of $E[g(X)]=\int g(x)f(x)\mathrm{d}x$, where $f$ is the PDF of your random variable $X$. Here $g(x)=x^{2020}.$

Comment: For the second part, it will be integral with bounds 2/3 and 1, x^2020 dx?

Comment: @PotatoQueen No, the expected value is calculated over the whole range of $[0,1]$. I'm not sure where you got 2/3 from; you asked two different questions, and 2/3 has nothing to do with the second.

Comment: @PotatoQueen If it is all clear, then please accept the answer $\left( \color{limegreen}{\checkmark} \right)$. It shows that you appreciate the work of the people. Check also all your other questions, please.